# How to set a value at angularjs autocomplete directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive given below.

```
var app = anugular.directive('autocomplete', ['autocomplete-keys', '$window', '$timeout', function(Keys, $window, $timeout) {
        return {
            template: '<input type="text" id="mm" class="autocomplete-input" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}"' +
                            'ng-class="inputClass"' +
                            'ng-model="searchTerm"' +
                            'ng-keydown="keyDown($event)"' +
                            'ng-blur="onBlur()" />' +

                        '<div class="autocomplete-options-container">' +
                            '<div class="autocomplete-options-dropdown" ng-if="showOptions">' +
                                '<div class="autocomplete-option" ng-if="!hasMatches">' +
                                    '<span style="color:red;">No Matches Found</span>' +
                                '</div>' +

                                '<ul class="autocomplete-options-list">' +
                                    '<li class="autocomplete-option" ng-class="{selected: isOptionSelected(option)}" ' +
                                        'ng-style="{width: optionWidth}"' +
                                        'ng-repeat="option in matchingOptions"' +
                                        'ng-mouseenter="onOptionHover(option)"' +
                                        'ng-mousedown="selectOption(option)"' +
                                        'ng-if="!noMatches">' +
                                        '<span>{{option[displayProperty]}}</span>' +
                                    '</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                options: '=',
                onSelect: '=',
                displayProperty: '@',
                inputClass: '@',
                clearInput: '@',
                placeHolder: '@'
            },
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.searchTerm = '';
                $scope.highlightedOption = null;
                $scope.showOptions = false;
                $scope.matchingOptions = [];
                $scope.hasMatches = false;
                $scope.selectedOption = null;

                $scope.isOptionSelected = function(option) {
                    return option === $scope.highlightedOption;
                };

                $scope.processSearchTerm = function(term) {
                    // console.log('ch-ch-ch-changin');
                    if (term.length > 0) {
                        if ($scope.selectedOption) {
                            if (term != $scope.selectedOption[$scope.displayProperty]) {
                                $scope.selectedOption = null;
                            } else {
                                $scope.closeAndClear();
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        var matchingOptions = $scope.findMatchingOptions(term);
                        $scope.matchingOptions = matchingOptions;
                        if (!$scope.matchingOptions.indexOf($scope.highlightedOption) != -1) {
                            $scope.clearHighlight();
                        }
                        $scope.hasMatches = matchingOptions.length > 0;
                        $scope.showOptions = true;
                    } else {
                        $scope.closeAndClear();
                    }
                };

                $scope.findMatchingOptions = function(term) {
                    return $scope.options.filter(function(option) {
                        var searchProperty = option[$scope.displayProperty];
                        if (searchProperty) {
                            var lowerCaseOption = searchProperty.toLowerCase();
                            var lowerCaseTerm = term.toLowerCase();
                            return lowerCaseOption.indexOf(lowerCaseTerm) != -1;
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                };

                $scope.findExactMatchingOptions = function (term) {


                    return $scope.options.filter(function(option) {
                        var lowerCaseOption = option[$scope.displayProperty].toLowerCase();
                        var lowerCaseTerm = term.toLowerCase();
                        return lowerCaseOption == lowerCaseTerm;
                    });
                };

                $scope.keyDown = function(e) {
                    switch(e.which) {
                        case Keys.upArrow:
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if ($scope.showOptions) {
                                $scope.highlightPrevious();
                            }
                            break;
                        case Keys.downArrow:
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if ($scope.showOptions) {
                                $scope.highlightNext();
                            } else {
                                $scope.showOptions = true;
                                if ($scope.selectedOption) {
                                    $scope.highlightedOption = $scope.selectedOption;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case Keys.enter:
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if ($scope.highlightedOption) {
                                $scope.selectOption($scope.highlightedOption);
                            } else {
                                var exactMatches = $scope.findExactMatchingOptions($scope.searchTerm);
                                if (exactMatches[0]) {
                                    $scope.selectOption(exactMatches[0]);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case Keys.escape:
                            $scope.closeAndClear();
                            break;
                    }
                };

                $scope.$watch('searchTerm', function (term) {

                    $scope.processSearchTerm(term);

                });

                $scope.highlightNext = function() {
                    if (!$scope.highlightedOption) {
                        $scope.highlightedOption = $scope.matchingOptions[0];
                    } else {
                        var currentIndex = $scope.currentOptionIndex();
                        var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1 == $scope.matchingOptions.length ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
                        $scope.highlightedOption = $scope.matchingOptions[nextIndex];
                    }
                };

                $scope.highlightPrevious = function() {
                    if (!$scope.highlightedOption) {
                        $scope.highlightedOption = $scope.matchingOptions[$scope.matchingOptions.length - 1];
                    } else {
                        var currentIndex = $scope.currentOptionIndex();
                        var previousIndex = currentIndex == 0 ? $scope.matchingOptions.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
                        $scope.highlightedOption = $scope.matchingOptions[previousIndex];
                    }
                };

                $scope.onOptionHover = function(option) {
                    $scope.highlightedOption = option;
                };

                $scope.$on('simple-autocomplete:clearInput', function() {
                    $scope.searchTerm = '';
                });

                $scope.clearHighlight = function() {
                    $scope.highlightedOption = null;
                };

                $scope.closeAndClear = function() {
                    $scope.showOptions = false;
                    $scope.clearHighlight();
                };

                $scope.selectOption = function(option) {

                    $scope.selectedOption = option;
                    $scope.onSelect(option);

                    if ($scope.clearInput != 'False' && $scope.clearInput != 'false') {
                        $scope.searchTerm = '';
                    } else {
                        $scope.searchTerm = option[$scope.displayProperty];
                    }

                    $scope.closeAndClear();
                };

                $scope.onBlur = function() {
                    $scope.closeAndClear();
                };

                $scope.currentOptionIndex = function() {
                    return $scope.matchingOptions.indexOf($scope.highlightedOption);
                };
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.optionWidth = '400px';
                var inputElement = elem.children('.autocomplete-input')[0];

                scope.setOptionWidth = function() {
                    // console.log(inputElement.offsetWidth);
                    $timeout(function() {
                        var pixelWidth = inputElement.offsetWidth > 400 ? 400 : inputElement.offsetWidth - 2;
                        scope.optionWidth = pixelWidth + 'px';
                    });
                };

                angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                    scope.setOptionWidth();
                });

                angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                    scope.setOptionWidth();
                });
            }
        };
    }]).factory('autocomplete-keys', function () {
        return {
            upArrow: 38,
            downArrow: 40,
            enter: 13,
            escape: 27
        };
    });
```

At laravel 5 view page like this:

```
<autocomplete options="allOrgData" ng-model="searchTerm"
                                      place-holder="Type Organization Name"
                                      on-select="onSelect"
                                      display-property="org_name"
                                      input-class="form-control"
                                      clear-input="false">
</autocomplete>
```

The list is loaded from:

```
$http.post("/api/getOrgForUserJson")
        .then(function(data){
                $scope.allOrgData = data.data;
        })
```

when I type and get name, this method called as selected item:

```
$scope.onSelect = function(selection) {
        $scope.org_id = selection.id;

    }
```

[image: display the console of selection on $scope.onSelect function]

[view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogNHT.png)
what the autocomplete does :
When I type organization name, it shows drop down list of the matched organization name. Which is load from database. (pointed on image: No. 1)
When I click on update button (pointed on image: No. 2), I need to set organization name to this autocomplete as selected value.

Comment: please display the console of `selection` on `$scope.onSelect` function.

Comment: @Hadi console of selection on $scope.onSelect function displayed.

Comment: `I need to set organization name to ...` How do this?

Comment: @Hadi  look at the view page[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogNHT.png], After clicking update button (pointed on image: No. 2). update button calls a function which initialize the data like this. $scope.name = user.name, where user is passed by pressing update button. Then it will shows at form. I want to initialize or selected the organization name to that autocomplete.

Comment: It Is Solved by using jquery:
`$('#mm').val(user.org_name);`